# Disable Item in Qt Combobox

Tags: c++, qt

I can't find a standard way to disable an individual item in a Qt combo box. Is there a facility to do this in Qt that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://theworldwideinternet.blogspot.com/2011/01/disabling-qcombobox-items.html):

```
// Get the index of the value to disable
QModelIndex index = ui.comboBox->model()->index(1, 0); 

// This is the effective 'disable' flag
QVariant v(0);

// the magic
ui.comboBox->model()->setData(index, v, Qt::UserRole - 1);
```

To enable again use:

```
QVariant v(1 | 32);
```

The model used maps the `flags` word to `Qt::UserRole - 1` -- that's what makes this code work. It's not a generic solution that would work with an arbitrary model.

Comment: It is invalid. Much better to make own list model (or proxy model), that will return `flags` properly.

Comment: All that it's needed is NOT returning `Qt::ItemIsEnabled` from the model's `flags()` method. `Qt::UserRole - 1` is a horrible hack you shouldn't be relying onto (it's not a public and documented role). Not to mention the `1 | 32` which doesn't even use the symbolic names.

Comment: @Lol4t0: Much better to have the default model support enabling & disabling QComboBox items.

Comment: @Sosukodo, just consider deafult models like examples and not smth you should really use in somehow complicated cases

Comment: @Lol4t0: That's a lame argument.

Comment: @Sosukodo, that's how things done. If you think about MV a bit, you'll get probably.

Answer (score 25):

Why hack.. We know the model is a QStandardItemModel...

```
model = dynamic_cast< QStandardItemModel * >( combobox->model() );
item = model->item( row, col );
item->setEnabled( false );
```

Clean, elegant, and no hack...

Answer (score 16):

In case your combo box is using a `QStandardItemModel` (which it does by default) then you may stay away from the `Qt::UserRole -1` hack (see [blog post](http://theworldwideinternet.blogspot.com/2011/01/disabling-qcombobox-items.html) to which Desmond refers to in his [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439773/disable-item-in-qt-combobox#11439859)):

```
const QStandardItemModel* model = qobject_cast<const QStandardItemModel*>(ui->comboBox->model());
QStandardItem* item = model->item(1);

item->setFlags(disable ? item->flags() & ~(Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled)
                       : Qt::ItemIsSelectable|Qt::ItemIsEnabled));
// visually disable by greying out - works only if combobox has been painted already and palette returns the wanted color
item->setData(disable ? ui->comboBox->palette().color(QPalette::Disabled, QPalette::Text)
                      : QVariant(), // clear item data in order to use default color
              Qt::TextColorRole);
```

Above code is a revised and more generic solution to my [comment](http://theworldwideinternet.blogspot.ch/2011/01/disabling-qcombobox-items.html?showComment=1392212546177#c4845363021949089541) to the blog post.

Comment: You can also set the item size hint to 0 height to make the entry disappear: item->setSizeHint(disable ? QSize(20,0) : QSize());

Comment: Why so complicated? Why not like here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598962/2492801

Answer (score 2):

You can use the model of a `QListWidget` as a proxy.

```
QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox(this);
QListWidget *contents = new QListWidget(combo);
contents->hide();
combo->setModel(contents->model());

/* Populate contents */
contents->addItem("...");    // Etcetera
```

Then, this method will disable an item:

```
void disableItem(int index)
{
    QListWidgetItem *item = contents->item(index);
    item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
}
```

Comment: I guess this approach makes things readable, but I think we should not forget to delete content when the combo box is deleted, right ?

Comment: There is no need to delete `contents` manually, as it has `combo` as its parent. So when `combo` is deleted, it deletes `contents` as well.