# How to style a disabled item in a QComboBox ? (qss)

Tags: qt, styles, qt5, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I used this code to disable an item inside a combobox
[Disable specific items in QComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915001/disable-specific-items-in-qcombobox) (it's ok)

And I would like a visual feedback. I would like to put the disabled item in red.

I tried this code but it doesn't nothing.

```
QComboBox::item:!enabled
{
    color:red;
}
```

I think that it's somewhere in the drop-down. But this code doesn't work also :

```
QComboBox::drop-down:item:!enabled {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up of the `QComboBox` is a `QAbstractItemView` and is styled using the descendant selector (from documentation).

so try as said below,

```
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:!enabled {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution suggested did not work for me, but the one below:

```
QComboBox::item:!enabled {
    color:red;
}
```