# ComboBox disable an item at a particular index

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have a combobox in qml in a as a `TableViewColummn` and I define it as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4


ListModel {
    id: comboModel

    ListElement {
        text: ""
        Index: -1
        Dims: -1
    }
}


TableViewColumn {
    id: imageTypeList
    role: "ImageType"
    title: "Image Type"
    width: 100
    delegate: Rectangle {
        ComboBox {
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            anchors.margins: 2
            model: comboModel
            onActivated : {
                console.log(comboModel.get(index).Index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is that if it is possible to `disable` a combobox menu item given a index to the item in the `ComboBox`. So, I would not like to change the underlying model but actually simply disable the item and not allow the user to select it.

Comment: You should to clarify your question. It is not clear what index do you mean - table row or `ComboBox` one? To disable Combobox for specified rows you can do `ComboBox { enabled: styleData.row !== 2 }`

Comment: @folibis Is it possible to do this from javascript code specifying the index?

Comment: @folibis I can do `enabled = false` in javascript but this disables the whole component,

Comment: What is the definition of `comboModel`?  Could you define it as a `QStandardItemModel` and adapt [this older `QComboBox` technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21740341/1296734)?

Comment: You need to specify `delegate` for your `ComboBox` where you should make specific item disabled.

Comment: What `QtQuick.Controls` version do you use?

Comment: I am using 1.4...I am actually on pyqt 5.6. I must say my imports are not very consistent...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to disable a ComboBox menu item ... and not allow the user to select it?

Sure, it is possible.

To do it using [Quick Controls 2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-index.html) you need to create [`ComboBox delegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#delegate-prop) this way:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Let's disable some items in ComboBox")

    ComboBox {
        id: control
        currentIndex: 0
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        model: [
            { text: "Enabled item.", enabled: true },
            { text: "Supposed to be disabled. Can't click on it.", enabled: false},
            { text: "Last, but enabled item.", enabled: true}
        ]
        width: 500
        textRole: "text"

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: control.width
            text: modelData.text
            font.weight: control.currentIndex === index ? Font.DemiBold : Font.Normal
            highlighted: ListView.isCurrentItem
            enabled: modelData.enabled
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you are using Quick Controls 1, you should provide your own implementation of `ComboBox` component.

Comment: That's great! Thanks.