# How to make combobox item not selectable in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to put itemSwitch2 not selectable if itemSwitch1 is "ON"
How can I desibale access to the itemSwitch2

```
function setSelectable(item, state)
{
    item.editable = state
}

StyledComboBox {
   id: itemSwitch1
   Layout.row: 0
   Layout.column: 1
   model: ["ON", "OFF"]
   currentIndex: (root.systemInfo.itemEn) ? 0 : 1
   onUpDownPressed:
   {
       currentIndex = !currentIndex;
   }
   onEditFinished: {
      dashboard.setSelectibale(itemSwitch2, false)
      optionProvider.upDate(currentIndexItem.text)
      itemLabel1.focus = true;
      updateTimer.running = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can use `enabled` for this

Comment: i tried to set enabled to "false",  but the item still selectable !

Comment: Please share a minimal working example so other stack-overflowers can try to reproduce and help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ComboBox disable an item at a particular index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742071/combobox-disable-an-item-at-a-particular-index)

Comment: No, not really !, in fact a want to disable selection of itemSwitch2 if itemSwitch1.text is "ON"

Comment: @Y.Hacene provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, but it is working:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Row {
        spacing: 2
        ComboBox {
            id: one
            width: 200
            model: [ "ON", "OFF" ]

            onCurrentIndexChanged: {
                if (currentIndex === find("ON")) {
                    two.enabled = false
                } else
                {
                    two.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }

        ComboBox {
            id: two
            width: 200
            model: [ "HELLO", "BYE" ]
        }
    }
}
```